# Error on Android xml layout: "Binary XML file: Error inflating class"

Tags: java, android, xml

I am using this xml file to create a page in Android:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ir.hiup.hadskalme.CategoryKids">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/backbala"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/categorylogo"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backbutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/backbutton"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.545"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/c1k"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/c1"
                    android:layout_height="220dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/c2k"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/c2"
                    android:layout_height="220dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/c4k"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/c4"
                    android:layout_height="220dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/c6k"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/c6"
                    android:layout_height="220dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/c11k"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cf11"
                    android:layout_height="220dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/c12k"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/c12"
                    android:layout_height="220dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </ScrollView>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

now on some devices I receive this error:

> lang.java.RuntimeException: (Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{ir.hiup.hadskalme/ir.hiup.hadskalme.CategoryKids}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #127: Error
>   inflating class )

Comment: have you tried taking tools:context="ir......" line out of your xml ??

Comment: For the view that ends on line 127, you have this attr `android:background="@drawable/cf11"`... is `cf11` a vector drawable?

Comment: @AalapPatel the whole of xml attached , and all codes same as this

Comment: @BenP yes that's a drawable

Comment: @Mahdi is it a PNG or `<vector>` asset?

Comment: Why are you nesting ConstraintLayouts? That's a red flag

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem once and it was not a inflate problem actually...

Maybe the inflate exception is not actually the problem, but really comes from another deeper issue in your layout that is then wrapped in an InflateException. A common issue is an out of memory exception when trying to inflate an imageview loading a drawable resource. If one of this resources has a high pixel resolution it would take a lot of memory causing then an inflate exception.

So basically verify that the pixel resolution in your drawables images are just the minimum necessary for your layout.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> tools:context="CategoryKids"

instead of

> tools:context="ir.hiup.hadskalme.CategoryKids"

As you can see in your error "ir.hiup.hadskalme/ir.hiup.hadskalme.CategoryKids" seems like the path is duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `@drawable/cf11` is a `<vector>` resource...

Vector drawables can't just be used exactly like a PNG drawable if the user's device is running older API versions. More information is available here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources.html#vector-drawables-backward-solution

> The way Android loads drawables, not every place that accepts a drawable ID, such as in an XML file, supports loading vector drawables.

To use a vector drawable for the background of a random `View`, use this code in your `Activity`:

```
Drawable d = VectorDrawableCompat.create(getResources(), R.drawable.cf11, getTheme());
findViewById(R.id.c11k).setBackground(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

Leonardo Cavazzani's solution was very correct. The real issue is the size of the background image used in the activity. I had a very high resolution background image and I was getting the same error. I looked all over the internet and everyone was suggesting to change theme, or Maven, or add "implement app compat." etc to the build gradle, but none of them worked. After reducing the resolution of my background image from over 5000x4000 pixels to only 200 pixels, my app stopped crashing. However, the strange thing is that I never had this issue before with the same background, except it started creeping after I updated to Android Studio 3.4.2.